# Assert for CUTE creates error

Tags: unit-testing, eclipse-cdt

I am using Eclipse CDT, MinGW and CUTE to create unit tests for a C++ project. However, when I write a test with "ASSERT", I get the error "Operator '+' cannot be resolved for type 'const char *' " Any idea why and how to solve it?

Comment: Can you give more detail, please?

Comment: Yes, please include a complete code example.

Comment: Just a simple code like:
void testFunction() {
double a = 0;
double b = 0;
ASSERT_EQUAL(a, b);
}
I get the error I mentionned

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Eclipse myself and I had this problem. Turns out I was linking a folder to another folder that did not exist in my project (I had previously added it, linked it, and then deleted it out of my project but the link was still there). Once you delete out the dead link, my project worked fine.

You can find the dead link by opening up the 'includes' folder (first item under your project) in the Project explorer and it should be grayed out.

Select the linked folder (folder with a key in upper right corner) > properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Includes > delete out the folder name that was grayed out. My project compiled after that.